# Type 'X' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I receive en error in typescript:

> message: 'Type 'TransitionStyles' cannot be used as an index type.'

I would like to know if it is possible to change my interface so it can also be used and an `index type`:

```
export interface TransitionStyles {
  entering: Object
  entered: Object
  exiting: Object
  exited: Object
  [key: string]: Object
}
```

or I am forced to use a different interface as:

`export type TransitionState = 'entering' | 'entered' | 'exiting' | 'exited'`

Comment: Use `keyof`. Also, don't use the `Object` type. Use `object` or `{}`, depending on which you mean.

Comment: I have tries [key: TransitionState ] but does not work, could you please provide me with an example

Comment: You have to use `type T = {[P in TransitionState]}`. It does not currently work for interfaces.

Comment: Could you write a full example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want something akin to

```
export interface TransitionStyles {
  entering: object;
  entered: object;
  exiting: object;
  exited: object;
}

export type TransitionState = keyof TransitionStyles;

export type PromisifiedTransitionStyles = {
  [P in TransitionState]: Promise<TransitionStyles[P]>
};
```

Note that if we reintroduce the `string` index signature, `[key: string]: TransitionState`, the key type `TransitionState`, will collapse to just `string` because in the type `string | "literal"` the more general type subsumes the more specific constituents of the union.